# How to correctly position graphic after flipping it

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics, cgaffinetransform

For the following lightning bolt graphic:

[image]

I'm trying to flip it while scaling like such:

```
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(newSize.width / initialSize.width, -1 * (newSize.height / initialSize.height));
CGMutablePathRef mutablePath = CGPathCreateMutableCopyByTransformingPath(shapeLayer.path, &transform);
shapeLayer.path = mutablePath;
CGPathRelease(mutablePath);
```

This is what happens:

[image]

I've tried a bunch of different ways to translate it but to no success:

```
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(newSize.width / 2, newSize.height / 2);
transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, newSize.width / initialSize.width, -1 * (newSize.height / initialSize.height));
transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, -newSize.width / 2, -newSize.height / 2);
```

Does anyone know the correct way to get my graphic back into the bounding box of the view?

Comment: Flipping is one thing, resizing is another. Which do you want to do?

Comment: @matt I need to do both simultaneously, the scale code I have is working on its own and as shown, it flips it, just repositions it out of the view and I don't know how to get it back in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matt's response pushed me in the right direction and this is ultimately how I was able to solve the problem:

```
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(newSize.width / initialSize.width, newSize.height / initialSize.height);
            
if (flipped)
{
    transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, 0, initialSize.height / 2.0);
    transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, 1, -1);
    transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, 0, -initialSize.height / 2.0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear what you're trying to do, and you have not supplied sufficient code even to generate the interface you've pictured, let alone to discover what the issue may be. However, the simplest thing is probably to transform the shape layer, not the path. The following code draws a non-symmetric shape in the center of the screen, and then flips it horizontally and enlarges it, operating round its center, so that it still in the center of the screen:

```
let shape = CAShapeLayer()
shape.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
let path = UIBezierPath()
path.move(to: .zero)
path.addLine(to: .init(x: 0, y: 100))
path.addLine(to: .init(x: 100, y: 100))
shape.path = path.cgPath
self.view.layer.addSublayer(shape)
shape.frame.origin = CGPoint(
    x: view.bounds.width / 2 - 50, 
    y: view.bounds.height / 2 - 50
)

let newsize = 1.5
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) {
    shape.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(-newsize, newsize, 0)
}
```

If you insist upon transforming the path, then the transform takes place around the origin (the top left), so you would need to move the center of the path to the origin, perform the scale transform, then move the center of the path back to the center.

```
let shape = CAShapeLayer()
shape.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
let path = UIBezierPath()
path.move(to: .zero)
path.addLine(to: .init(x: 0, y: 100))
path.addLine(to: .init(x: 100, y: 100))
shape.path = path.cgPath
self.view.layer.addSublayer(shape)
shape.frame.origin = CGPoint(
    x: view.bounds.width / 2 - 50, 
    y: view.bounds.height / 2 - 50
)

let newsize = 1.5
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) {
    path.apply(CGAffineTransform(translationX: -50, y: -50))
    path.apply(CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -newsize, y: newsize))
    path.apply(CGAffineTransform(translationX: 50, y: 50))
    shape.path = path.cgPath
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir, this helped me find my way to the answer with my specific code (sorry I didn't include enough, always hard to know how much to include). Will post in a little.